# Mongodb projection returning a given position

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to do something as simple as return a subarray of a document. So my query is:

```
db.mydocs.findOne({_id:ObjectId("af7a85f758e338d762000012")},{'house.0.room.4.windows':1});
```

I want to return only that value. But I get an empty structure. I know I could do it with $slice. But as far as I know, I can't do it for subarrays. I mean: `{'house':{'$slice':0}}` would work. But I don't know how to get house 0 and room 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use chained [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#proj._S_slice) operators for this to work:

```
db.mydocs.findOne(
  {_id:ObjectId("af7a85f758e338d762000012")}, 
  {"house" : {$slice : [0,1]},      // house.0
   "house.room" :{$slice : [3,1]}, // house.0.room.4
   "house.room.windows" : 1});      // house.0.room.4.windows
```

The resulting document will look like this, i.e. the arrays are still arrays (which is helpful when mapping to strongly typed languages):

```
house : [ { room : [ { windows : foo } ] } ]
```

from [the documentation:](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

> **Tip**: MongoDB does not support projections of portions of arrays *except* when using the `$elemMatch` and `$slice` projection operators.

P.S: I find it irritating that `house` and `room` are arrays, but have singular names, esp. because `windows` *is* plural.

Comment: Can java use the same syntax?